# Get rid of yellow mark on network icon on windows server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

a yellow mark is displayed over the icon network in Windows server.

How can i determine why and get rid of it ?

The server itself does have working internet connection for both ipv4 and ipv6.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetPrefixPolicy

Prefix                                                       Precedence      Label
------                                                       ----------      -----
3ffe::/16                                                             1         12
fec0::/10                                                             1         11
::/96                                                                 1          3
fc00::/7                                                              3         13
2001::/32                                                             5          5
2002::/16                                                            30          2
::ffff:0:0/96                                                        35          4
::/0                                                                 40          1
::1/128                                                              50          0
```

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetOffloadGlobalSetting

```
ReceiveSideScaling           : Enabled
ReceiveSegmentCoalescing     : Enabled
Chimney                      : Disabled
TaskOffload                  : Enabled
NetworkDirect                : Enabled
NetworkDirectAcrossIPSubnets : Blocked
PacketCoalescingFilter       : Disabled
```

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetNeighbor

```
ifIndex IPAddress                                          LinkLayerAddress   State       PolicyStore    
------- ---------                                          ----------------   -----       -----------    
12      ff02::1:ffff:ff                                    3333ffff00ff       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1:fffe:59d6                                  3333fffe59d6       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1:ff52:af80                                  3333ff52af80       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1:ff42:e480                                  3333ff42e480       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1:ff00:3034                                  3333ff003034       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1:3                                          333300010003       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::16                                           333300000016       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::2                                            333300000002       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      ff02::1                                            333300000001       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      fe80::eaba:70ff:fe42:e480                          e8ba7042e480       Reachable   ActiveStore    
12      fe80::1ee6:c7ff:fe52:af80                          1ce6c752af80       Reachable   ActiveStore    
12      2001:xxx0:x:7ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                        000573a00000       Reachable   ActiveStore    
15      ff02::16                                           255.255.255.255... Permanent   ActiveStore    
15      fe80::eaba:70ff:fe42:e480                          255.255.255.255... Unreachable ActiveStore    
15      fe80::1ee6:c7ff:fe52:af80                          255.255.255.255... Unreachable ActiveStore    
1       ff02::16                                                              Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      224.0.0.252                                        01005e0000fc       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      224.0.0.22                                         01005e000016       Permanent   ActiveStore    
12      xx.59.xx.254                                       0007b4000003       Reachable   ActiveStore    
1       224.0.0.22                                                            Permanent   ActiveStore
```

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetIPInterface

```
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
12      Ethernet                        IPv6                  1500               5 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
15      Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Inte... IPv6                  1280              50 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
13      isatap.{163FD72E-A61A-4CC3-B... IPv6                  1280              50 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              50 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
12      Ethernet                        IPv4                  1500               5 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              50 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

Answer (score 2):

Th yellow mark indicates that Windows has determined the status of the network connection is 'Limited'.  This status indicator is determined by the Network Connection Status Indicator, part of the Network Location Awareness Service (NlaSvc).  It's described in [this Technet blogpost.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2012/12/20/the-network-connection-status-icon/)

Briefly, it tests for internet connectivity by attempting to download a text file from `http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`, so in order to satisfy this test and remove the warning icon you'll need the necessary DNS and HTTP access to do that.  Once that's achievable, restarting the NLA service should be sufficient to change the indicated status.

> Every time a network configuration event occurs (meaning that
>   something has changed in the network configuration), the NCSI process
>   performs several tests to identify the network’s connectivity status.
>   The first step NCSI performs is a DNS query for www.msftncsi.com. The
>   second step is and HTTP get request for
>   http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt. This file is a plain-text file and
>   contains only the text “Microsoft NCSI.” Last it will perform a DNS
>   query for dns.msftncsi.com.

Answer (score 0):

Is the machine able to resolve external DNS names? External DNS resolving needs to be in place for that icon to go.